# Array->field[name] or Array->field["name"]

Tags: c++, string

I'm modifying a program of ROS (robot operating system) in c++

I want the functions of the buttons to be changeable.
The line to read the button-state is:

```
joy->buttons[LB];
joy->buttons[RB];
```

from my configfile I get a string which says "LB" or "RB".
Now my question is:
How can I take the String to read the button-state?
my thought was:

```
joy->buttons["LB"] so that my line will be joy->buttons[myString];
```

Does this work that way?

Comment: This depends on the context. How is `joy` defined? What's the definition of the *class* of `joy`? How is `buttons` inside this class defined?

Answer (score 4):

It does not work for native arrays which use numeric indices only. However, you can use a container like `std::map` which can work like an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Or you can translate your string to numeric index:

```
int index;
if(myString == "LB")
    index = 0;
else if(myString == "RB")
    index = 1;
// else: set default value!

joy->buttons[index];
```